# SQL Subquery to get first record

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to execute a query something like below.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ROWNUM),
A.Name,
B.Order,
(SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROUND(LAST_ORDER_AMOUNT,5) FROM ORDERS WHERE ID=A.id AND REQUEST_LEVEL='N' ORDER BY O_DATE DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM =1) AS AMOUNT
FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B
ON A.TYPE_CODE = B.ENTITY_TYPE
```

But this gives me A.ID is invalid error in oracle. I need to get the first record from inner query as it will return multiple records.

Can someone please let me know how can i bind these tables to achieve my goal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?  This might be hard to believe, but SQL code that doesn't work isn't nearly as effective at communicating what you want as sample data and desired results.

Comment: The SQL looks syntactically correct. So it is strange you get the error that A.ID is invalid. Your table1 does have a column named ID, right?

Comment: Hi Gordan, it says a.id is invalid. i think from the inner sub query cannot see the attributes of the outer sql when it is two levels down.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite subquery using `WITH` clause, not exactly sure on syntax but should be something like following.

```
WITH    AmountQuery
      AS (
           SELECT ID
               ,ROUND(LAST_ORDER_AMOUNT, 5) AS AmountValue
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY O_DATE DESC ) AS RN
            FROM ORDERS
            WHERE REQUEST_LEVEL = 'N'
         )
SELECT TO_CHAR(ROWNUM)
       ,A.Name
       ,B.Order
       ,C.AmountValue
    FROM Table1 A
    LEFT JOIN Table2 B
        ON A.TYPE_CODE = B.ENTITY_TYPE
    LEFT JOIN AmountQuery C
        ON a.ID = c.ID
           AND c.RN = 1
```

here is SQLFiddle to show how it works.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/696b6/36

Comment: Will this actually work in Oracle? Will it not give the same error that the OP complained about (line `WHERE ID = A.id
`)? I thought in Oracle you couldn't reference tables in 2-level deep sub-query.

Comment: @RacilHilan I rewrote it using `WITH` clause

Comment: @Valdimir- Thank you very much. i looked your sqlfiddle example and was able to restructure my query. Thanks again. keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, LIMIT will do the job for you selecting just one record from the subquery (It worked for me in MySQL. I do not have Oracle, but I think it may be similar). Try something like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ROWNUM),
A.Name,
B.Order,
COALESCE( C.AMOUNT ) as AMOUNT,
FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B
ON A.TYPE_CODE = B.ENTITY_TYPE
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ROUND(LAST_ORDER_AMOUNT,5) AS AMOUNT FROM ORDERS WHERE REQUEST_LEVEL='N' ORDER BY  O_DATE DESC ) C ON C.ID = A.id
group by A.id;
```

Comment: `Limit` is not available in Oracle. I think they've added it in 12c, but not sure.

Comment: I have changed the query to use COALESCE, which should work on ORACLE. I think that by modifying the query now, it should work.